# Parallax background-size 100%, Text won't scale

Tags: css

Which CSS property do I need in order to scale the content full screen.  I have the following:

```
.parallax7 {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

[nextpresso.moyeecoffee.com/dev](http://nextpresso.moyeecoffee.com/dev)

Or another solution perhaps? They want all the images to be seen on mobile at 100%.

Comment: Try background-size:cover;

Comment: Not for me, guess I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all aspect ration of the image is wrong for mobile, but anyway if you need to fit it in viewport then try this

```
.parallax7 {
   background-color: #FF783E;
   background-image: url('../images/parallax-bg-7.jpg');
   background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

it will set width to 100% and automaticly find height for image..

background-color will fill 'remain' area ( so it won't look so ugly )

Answer (score 0):

All is not working fellas. It must be a problem which should be possible to fix right, after all, it's css..